# Oracle apex 5.1 calling interact grid inside modal dialog

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an oracle apex interactive grid region. I want to call this region in a modal dialog box while clicking a button. The template of the region is set to 'inline dialog'. I have set a static id to the region which is used for calling this region from javascript(code- javascript:openmodal('edit') ) while button click. It works well if the region is interactive report but do not work with interactive grid. Any solution?

Comment: try modal page instead of modal dialog ...

Comment: I can't use modal page , since other regions are also there, which are displayed in a normal page.

Comment: Ok, provide more details on error ...

Comment: I have 5regions in my page. one of the region in my page is kept as modal dialog, which opens when I click the button 'EDIT'.it is used for selecting records. This modal region was initially kept as interactive report type, but when interactive report is called inside a modal dialog, it shows some abnormal behavior.The column heading disappears ,column heading scrolls up, and there are some stretching problem also. I can't use the classic reports since it's heading is not fixed when I scroll. So I decided to use interactive grid. but it shows a blank region when used inside modal region.

Answer (score -2):

1 CLIC IN REGION
2 CLIC IN ATTRIBUTES 
3 FIND AND CLIC HEADING 
4 FIND Fixed To REGION 
5 Maximum Report Height 500

TRY IT